# How to set localStorage for mulitple origins like with Storage.setCookies in Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-devtools-protocol

I would like to set localStorage and cookies before navigating to any page in Chrome DevTools Protocol.

Comment: `Storage.setCookies` looks like what you need for cookies.